# How to invert mouse in overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

Most first person shooter has invert mouse option.

I do not see that option anywhere.

Where can I find it?

Comment: You don't see an "invert look" option under "Controls" in the options menu?

Comment: As shown in [this screenshot](http://www.overclock3d.net/gfx/articles/2016/05/06070442634l.jpg)?

Answer (score 4):

The option you're looking for is called **Invert Look** and can be found under the Control options menu, on the **MOUSE** section, right next to Sensitivity. You can also change this option individually with each character by using the drop-down select on the same options menu.

[@pushasha](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276570/how-to-invert-mouse-in-overwatch?rq=1#comment388786_276570) has provided a screenshot of said menu on his comment, so I'll add it here as well.

[image: Invert look, options menu]